# How to store an interface in an entity avoiding JSON errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using an entity 'User' which needs an interface 'match'.
I store it like this

```
    @Column({
    nullable: true,
    type: 'json',
})
public currentMatch: Match | null;
```

But my match interface stores a User so when I try to save it to the databse, it triggers this error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: Turn off relations or don't populate it.

Comment: Why store json in a db? You can not easily query it.

Comment: i was told to store it as json because i didn't know how to store an interface in my entity